# At Hover, how to change color of an image and text simultaneously which are in a single div?

Tags: html, css, image, colors, hover

I want these images and captions get the colour changed on hover but not separately but when one clicks on text image should also change the colour. Not the background but the colour of those link text and images/
This is my code :

```
<div class="whitenavigation">
      <nav class="navicontext">
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="img/Icons/1.PNG" alt="PROGRAMMES">
          <a class="caption" href="#">PROGRAMMES</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="img/Icons/2%20.PNG" alt="Faculty">
          <a class="caption" href="#">FACULTY</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="img/Icons/3%20.PNG" alt="Faculty">
          <a class="caption" href="#">RESEARCH</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="img/Icons/4%20.PNG" alt="Faculty">
          <a class="caption" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="img/Icons/5%20.PNG" alt="Faculty">
          <a class="caption" href="#">ADMISSION</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="img/Icons/6.PNG" alt="Faculty">
          <a class="caption" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Here is the css code that I have applied and tried to get reslts. I got change of color on hover for text and images differently. For images I used the grayscale property of css. It will work when we hover on images but for text we have to hover seperately. I want them at one time change:

```
.whitenavigation{
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     width:1080px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: white;
}
 .navicon{
     vertical-align: top;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 14px;
     margin-left: 50px;
}
 .navicon img{
     width:30px;
     height: 30px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.navicon img:hover{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    cursor: pointer;
    }
 .caption {
     display: block;
     color: black;
}
 .navicon a:hover {
     color:#e96803;
}
 .navicontext{
     margin-top: 10px;
     float: right;
}`
```

Comment: how do you change the color of an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover in css to change background color of the divs easily. Here is the code for what i have done.

Link to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daWNEj)

```css
.navicon{
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.navicon:hover{
  transition: 0.4s;
  background-color:orange;
}
.caption{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitenavigation">
      <nav class="navicontext">
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/elite-medical-science/512/blood-sample-512.png" alt="PROGRAMMES" width=150 >
          <a class="caption" href="#">PROGRAMMES</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/elite-medical-science/512/blood-sample-512.png" alt="Faculty" width=150 >
          <a class="caption" href="#">FACULTY</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/elite-medical-science/512/blood-sample-512.png" alt="Faculty" width=150 >
          <a class="caption" href="#">RESEARCH</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/elite-medical-science/512/blood-sample-512.png" alt="Faculty" width=150 >
          <a class="caption" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/elite-medical-science/512/blood-sample-512.png" alt="Faculty" width=150 >
          <a class="caption" href="#">ADMISSION</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/elite-medical-science/512/blood-sample-512.png" alt="Faculty" width=150 >
          <a class="caption" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @S.Ruka but I don't wanted to change the background of those apple images. I want to change the colour of that image. Actually, I am using png images like icons for my navigation bar and when I hover on them I want those icons to change into orange with text at the same time which is just below of the icon.

Comment: you mean for icons with transparent background. Right?

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. Please check if this is what you want.

Comment: Bro icon is still black. Can you change that icon from black to orange not the background

Comment: What if you make the image background white and icon area transparent
Then when you change background color icon color will change

Comment: or you can take image in svg format. if so you can change icon color easily.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css on hover of parent element

```
.navicon:hover img{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navicon:hover a {
     color:#e96803;
}
```

```css
.whitenavigation{
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     width:1080px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: white;
}
 .navicon{
     vertical-align: top;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 14px;
     margin-left: 50px;
}
 .navicon img{
     width:30px;
     height: 30px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.navicon:hover img{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    cursor: pointer;
    }
 .caption {
     display: block;
     color: black;
}
 .navicon:hover a {
     color:#e96803;
}
.navicontext{
     margin-top: 10px;
     float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitenavigation">
      <nav class="navicontext">
        <div class="navicon">
         <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/64/000000/name.png">
          <a class="caption" href="#">PROGRAMMES</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/edit.png">
          <a class="caption" href="#">FACULTY</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/synchronize.png">
          <a class="caption" href="#">RESEARCH</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/picture.png">
          <a class="caption" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/opened-folder.png">
          <a class="caption" href="#">ADMISSION</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navicon">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/services.png">
          <a class="caption" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Hiren Vaghasiya, your code worked finely and now my problem is solved and you are my first helper on StackOverflow :)

Comment: @KashifKhalid Welcome Mate

Answer (score -1):

Use it in CSS file. this should work

```
.navicon, caption: hover{
// your color changing CSS
}
```

Comment: No, it's not changing the colour of text or image. But when I apply background colour change it will change the whole div background. I want to change only text and Image colour simultaneously

Comment: @KashifKhalid then try changing the .whitenavigation: hover{} to .navicon, .caption: hover{}

Comment: @KashifKhalid i have updated the answer, kindly have a look. kindly Upvote this answer or accept it as answered If this helps you or works for you.

Comment: where to share?

Comment: you can share it in your question itself